# Losing points for partially completed destination tickets in Ticket to Ride

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring, ticket-to-ride-europe

I have the game Ticket to Ride: Europe and I'm a little confused about the points for destination tickets. I read somewhere that if you don't start to complete one of your destination tickets, at the end you don't lose any points. Not sure if this rule it's real, but if it is...

Let's say that I have done these 2 tickets: Frankfurt-Wilno, Danzig-Kiev and I have one more route from Wilno-Athina. Does the last one count as unfinished or does it count as not started?

I consider it started because it goes from Wilno to Kyiv and from there you can continue towards Bucharest-Sofia-Athina.

So, if you can clear things up.
What's the deal with the unfinished and not started tickets?

[image]

Answer (score 16):

There's no such thing as a ticket that's "started" vs "not started". Unless it refers to the act of taking the ticket. When you take a ticket, you must complete that route, or lose points for not having completed it. It doesn't matter if you've touched those cities with any trains or not.

Answer (score 11):

At the end of a game of Ticket to Ride, when final scoring happens, your destination tickets can only have one of two statuses: complete or incomplete. As per the [rules](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf) for destination tickets on page 6 (emphasis mine):

> The cities listed on a Destination Ticket represent travel goals for the player; they can result in a bonus or a penalty. If, by the end of the game, a player has created a continuous path of his color plastic trains between the two cities named on a Destination Ticket he holds, he scores the additional points indicated by the Point Value on the Ticket. **If he has failed to complete a continuous path between those cities, he deducts the Point Value on the Ticket from his total score.**

The scoring is clarified on page 7 under *Calculating Scores* (emphasis mine):

> Players must then reveal all of their Destination Tickets. **The value of successfully completed tickets is added to their total score. The value for any incomplete Tickets is deducted from their total score.**

If a player drew and kept a destination ticket, whether it has been started by the player or not, it is considered incomplete at the end of the game, leading to a loss of points.